# Problem with PGFplots and GNUplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I am trying to plot some functions, however I run into the problem that I get the same output for different functions

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]


\begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
 title={$a=0.2$},
xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
    ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
    legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
    ytick distance=0.0005,
    restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]
\addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] plot gnuplot{((0.2)^(1/10)+(1-0.2)^(1/10)*x^(1-1/10))/(0.999^(1/10)*(0.999^(1-1/10)*0.2^(1/10)+(1-0.2)^(1/10)*x^(1-1/10))) -1)};
\addlegendentry{$\xi=1/10$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

\begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
 title={$a=0.2$},
xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
    ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
    legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
    ytick distance=0.0005,
    restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

\addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot
{((0.2)^(1/2)+(1-0.2)^(1/2)*x^(1-1/2))/(0.999^(1/2)*(0.999^(1-1/2)*0.2^(1/2)+(1-0.2)^(1/2)*x^(1-1/2))) -1)};
\addlegendentry{$\xi=1/2$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

\begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
 title={$a=0.2$},
xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
    ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
    legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
    ytick distance=0.0005,
    restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

\addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot
{((0.2)^(99/100)+(1-0.2)^(99/100)*x^(1-99/100))/(0.999^(99/100)*(0.999^(1-99/100)*0.2^(99/100)+(1-0.2)^(99/100)*x^(1-99/100))) -1)};
\addlegendentry{$\xi=99/100$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

While compiling I also briefly get shown the message "line 2 unexpected or unrecognized token", however I have no idea how to fix this. I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please note that `plot gnuplot` is not entirely correct, it should be only `gnuplot`. Then AFAIK in `gnuplot` expressions `^` is to be replaced by `**`. Also please avoid passing `scale=0.7` to the `tikzpicture`, pass it to the `axis` if you really want to use it.

Comment: @marmot, `plot gnuplot` does still work for backward compatibility reasons. Also `^` does work and will be translated correctly to `**` before the expression is passed to gnuplot ...

Comment: ... maybe it has something to do with the fact that there is one superfluous closing brace (`)`) which yields to this result?

Comment: @Paul Ostmann, have you try to plot it directly in gnuplot?

Comment: I do not know if it's the case here, but in my gnuplot 1/2 is 0, like 1/10 or 99/100... Integer division. Try 1.0/2 etc etc... Can't check now, too late in the night ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `gnuplot` does not recognize fractions as floats. Therefore, please whether place a point at the end of the fraction:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}

            \centering

            \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]


            \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
            title={$a=0.2$},
            xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
            ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
            legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
            ytick distance=0.0005,
            restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]
            \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] plot gnuplot{((0.2)^(1/10.)+(1-0.2)^(1/10.)*x^(1-1/10.))/(0.999^(1/10.)*(0.999^(1-1/10.)*0.2^(1/10.)+(1-0.2)^(1/10.)*x^(1-1/10.)))-1};
            \addlegendentry{$\xi=1/10$}

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]

            \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
            title={$a=0.2$},
            xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
            ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
            legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
            ytick distance=0.0005,
            restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

            \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot{((0.2)^(1/2.)+(1-0.2)^(1/2.)*x^(1-1/2.))/(0.999^(1/2.)*(0.999^(1-1/2.)*0.2^(1/2.)+(1-0.2)^(1/2.)*x^(1-1/2.)))-1};
            \addlegendentry{$\xi=1/2$}

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]

            \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
            title={$a=0.2$},
            xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
            ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
            legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
            ytick distance=0.0005,
            restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

            \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot{((0.2)^(99/100.)+(1-0.2)^(99/100.)*x^(1-99/100.))/(0.999^(99/100.)*(0.999^(1-99/100.)*0.2^(99/100.)+(1-0.2)^(99/100.)*x^(1-99/100.)))-1};
            \addlegendentry{$\xi=99/100$}
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

or substitute the fractions with decimal values:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

    \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]


    \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
     title={$a=0.2$},
    xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
        ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
        legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
        ytick distance=0.0005,
        restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]
    \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] plot gnuplot{((0.2)^(0.1)+(1-0.2)^(0.1)*x^(1-0.1))/(0.999^(0.1)*(0.999^(1-0.1)*0.2^(0.1)+(1-0.2)^(0.1)*x^(1-0.1)))-1};
    \addlegendentry{$\xi=1/10$}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]

    \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
     title={$a=0.2$},
    xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
        ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
        legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
        ytick distance=0.0005,
        restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

    \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot{((0.2)^(0.5)+(1-0.2)^(0.5)*x^(1-0.5))/(0.999^(0.5)*(0.999^(1-0.5)*0.2^(0.5)+(1-0.2)^(0.5)*x^(1-0.5)))-1};
    \addlegendentry{$\xi=1/2$}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=0.7]

    \begin{axis}[title style={yshift=-1ex,},
     title={$a=0.2$},
    xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=$p_2$,
        ylabel = {$\Delta x_1^{a,b}/x_1^{a,b}$},     xmin=0, xmax=2,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.003,
        legend style={legend pos=north west,legend cell align={left}},   enlargelimits=false, width={10cm},height={8cm}, xtick distance=0.5,
        ytick distance=0.0005,
        restrict y to domain=0:0.003,samples=500]

    \addplot[mark=none, color=black, dashed] gnuplot{((0.2)^(0.99)+(1-0.2)^(0.99)*x^(1-0.99))/(0.999^(0.99)*(0.999^(1-0.99)*0.2^(0.99)+(1-0.2)^(0.99)*x^(1-0.99)))-1};
    \addlegendentry{$\xi=99/100$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I suspected, +1. The problem is not that gnuplot "doesn't recognize" fractions, is that it uses the C-language style of automatic type promotion. So, 1/2 is an operation between integers, and uses integer division, which gives 0. If one of the two is float, it uses float (this is why 1/2. is 0.5). You'll find this behavior in (most?) programming languages.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this indeed fixed the problem. I have one more question though: Do you by any chance know what the error message "line 2 unexpected or unrecognized token" means, because I'm kinda curious and a google search did yield any helpful results.

Comment: @ Rmano, yes you are/were right about [integers division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers). Thank you for the hint! And the further explanation

Comment: @ Paul Ostmann, see comment of [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow)` about superfluous closing brace `...-1)}`. Delete it: `...-1}` and then compiles without errors. I've corrected it in the asnwer, too.